# Usage of "from" in indicating time expression

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> All because of my fine efforts from last 2 or 3 months.

Is the usage of '**from**'  correct in the above sentence? If not then with what word should it be replaced?

And when and how should one use '**from**' in indicating time expression like

> From yesterday
>
> From 2 PM
>
> From last min or year.

Is the usage of **from** correct here?

Answer (score 2):

[from](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/from) - *used to show the ​time when **something ​starts** ...*

> The library is open **from** Monday to Friday
>
> The new rule will apply **from** September 1st.

[over](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/over) - ***during*** something, or while doing something

> We were in Italy **over** the summer
>
> I have been very busy **over** the last few months

[since](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/since) - ***from*** a ​particular ​time in the past ... **until now**

> I have been working here **since** 2012
>
> I haven't eaten **since** breakfast

**from** is used to specify when something started (you can use **since** as well for this, if it is still happening) or when something will start.

**over** is used specify a period of time- usually while something else is happening.

Your first sentence is therefore best written as:

> All because of my fine efforts **over** the last 2 or 3 months.

For the other three sentences, they are all in the past, so if the situation still exists it would be better to use **since**.

> **since** yesterday
>
> **since** 2 PM
>
> **since** last year.

We don't really say "since last minute": a minute is to short a time interval for **from** or **since**. You might instead say something like

> I only started a minute **ago**.

Answer (score 0):

from used to show the ​time when something ​starts or the ​time when it was made or first ​existed

from cambridage dictionary.

You can see from above explaination, you must put a date/time point after from but not a period.